# pass the parameter in javascript url

Tags: javascript

I want to pass the parameter value in url.I have the parameter 'redir'.redir value is changed dynamically as 1,2,3,4,5,... or any number I passed the redir value from php.I passed the value to the newpage() function. I want to pass dynamic redir value as in rec_resume_post.php?req_id=1 or  rec_resume_post.php?req_id=2.

```
<?php
 echo '<tr><td>'.$title.'</td><td>'.$c_name.'</td><td>'.$e_first_name.'</td><td>'.$num.'</td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="newpage('.$req_id.');" /></td></tr>'; 
?>
 <script>
   function newpage(redir){
    window.alert(redir);
    window.open("rec_resume_post.php?req_id=redir");
      }
```

Comment: `window.open("rec_resume_post.php?req_id=" + redir);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
window.open("rec_resume_post.php?req_id=" + redir);
```

So it would be like this:

```
<?php
 echo '<tr><td>'.$title.'</td><td>'.$c_name.'</td><td>'.$e_first_name.'</td><td>'.$num.'</td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="newpage('.$req_id.');" /></td></tr>'; 
?>
 <script>
   function newpage(redir){
    window.alert(redir);
    window.open("rec_resume_post.php?req_id"+ redir);
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the variable to the string.

```
<?php
 echo '<tr><td>'.$title.'</td><td>'.$c_name.'</td><td>'.$e_first_name.'</td><td>'.$num.'</td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="newpage('.$req_id.');" /></td></tr>'; 
?>
 <script>
   function newpage(redir){
    window.alert(redir);
    window.open("rec_resume_post.php?req_id"+ redir);
      }
```

Edited: Suggested the join method for combining strings. But as Rahul pointed out below, using + is the best way to combine strings.

Comment: I dont think that .join() is going to be useful here!

Comment: Maybe not, but I just want to show another way to combine strings in javascript. I personally don't like all the '+' characters when combining strings in javascript.

Comment: I'm curious what you think is the best practise Rahul, I'm sometimes wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Not sure about the best practise but yes as far as the performance is concerned "+" is definetly the fastest. Here is a test demo to justify that: http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join

Comment: Also what I have seen is that when we are concatenating the url then 99% of the time we use the "+" operator. So my assumption is that its because of the performance issue and hence a recommended practise

Answer (score 1):

You need to concat your string like this:

```
window.open("rec_resume_post.php?req_id="+redir);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the window.open line like follows:

```
window.open("rec_resume_post.php?req_id=" + redir);
```